# MongoDb Atlas - How to identify private endpoint connection strings for serverless instances?

Tags: mongodb, terraform, mongodb-atlas

I am using terraform to set up a serverless instance with two private endpoints. I want to then store the private endpoint aware connection strings in a key vault.

If I get the connection strings for my serverless instance it will return something like:

```
connection_strings_private_endpoint_srv = [“mongodb+srv:/my-serverless-instance-pe-0.asdfasdf.mongodb.net”, “mongodb+srv:/my-serverless-instance-pe-1.asdfasdf.mongodb.net”,]
```

I am trying to find a way to tell which connection string is for which private endpoint so I can store it accordingly. The only way it seems is to make sure one gets created before the other so you know which will be pe-0 and which would be pe-1 but I would rather not do it that way.

If I request all the private endpoints for the instance, none of the attributes correspond to the connection string or what number private endpoint it is.

I tried to find the info I need in the attributes returned by the following but there is nothing helpful there.

```
output "private_endpoints_data" {
  value = data.mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoints_service_serverless.endpoints
}

output "serverless_instance_data" {
  value = data.mongodbatlas_serverless_instance.serverless_instance
}
```